# Sending data to other class is getting null in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, class, oop, dart, model

I am using model to convert data to map. When I pass value to the model from class A it returns a map and then I am passing the returned value (Map) to class B. Before sending the valuing I am printing value in class A (It is showing data) but in class B it is showing null. here is class A function.

```
///Dummy Data remove later
   jobPostModel = JobPostModel(
      jobPost: 'Web design',
    );

   var data = jobPostModel.toJob(jobPostModel);
   print('before $data');
   JobPostScreen8(data);
```

Here is Model class function which is returning Map

```
class JobPostModel {
  String jobPost;

 JobPostModel(
      {this.jobPost});

  Map toJob(JobPostModel info){
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['jobPost'] = info.jobPost;
    return data;
  }
  factory JobPostModel.fromJob(Map<String, dynamic> data){
    return JobPostModel(
      jobPost: data['jobPost']
    );
  }
}
```

and here is other class where i must display data but it is showing null

```
class JobPostScreen8 extends StatefulWidget {
  Map jobPostModelMapData;

  JobPostScreen8([this.jobPostModelMapData]);

  @override
  _JobPostScreen8State createState() => _JobPostScreen8State();
}

class _JobPostScreen8State extends State<JobPostScreen8> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('after ${widget.jobPostModelMapData}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it show anything or is the value null?

Comment: It just print null

Comment: try using this.widget.jobPostModelMapData, does that help? please provide the output of that

Comment: I have found the solution and posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I was passing directly to class B. All I need is to use Navigation.

```
BlocListener<JobBloc, JobState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is JobSuccessfulState)
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => JobPostScreen8(state.data)));
})
```

here is Bloc

```
if (event is PreviewPostJob) {
        yield JobSuccessfulState(_updateModel());
      }
```

and state

```
class JobSuccessfulState extends JobState {
  var data;

  JobSuccessfulState([this.data]);
}
```